# Cast the return value of a function that returns a casted type

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I want to know from compiler perspective what happens when a casted type is returned to a function which also typecast the returned value. I want to know what are the advantages and disadvantages of explicit type casting a return value.

```
static uint16_t sResult_U16;

static uint16_t GetMyResult(void) 
{
    return (uint16_t)sResult_U16;
}
```

vs

```
static uint16_t GetMyResult(void) 
{
    return sResult_U16;
}
```

What will compiler translate, if a the return type is not same as the function type? For example.

```
static int16_t sResult_S16;

static uint16_t GetMyResult(void) 
{
    return sResult_S16;
}
```

Comment: This question is focused on more than a question. Be specific when writing a question next time. (i.e. what will..., what are the adv..., what happens...)

Comment: @RohanBari I disagree, there seems to be only one question.

Comment: Returning from a function is the same as doing `return type foo = cast_expression`.

Comment: What specific architecture are we talking about?  Is the width of the original type and the return type always the same, or are you also asking what happens if one is a larger type than the other?

Comment: @JohnZwinck 32bit Arm architecture

Comment: @RohanBari would you like to answer? if you feel there are multiple questions inside the post would you like to elaborate each question and try to explain.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Why does it matter? `uint16_t` and `int16_t` are portable 2's complement and the code posted is 100% portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a compiler's perspective, `(uint16_t)sResult_U16;` is nonsense since the type of `sResult_U16` is already the same as the return type. It will simply ignore the useless cast in the first case.

In the second case, you use a different type than the return type. The variable is then converted to the same type as the return type, which is in practice done by taking the raw binary representation of the signed variable and convert it to the raw binary unsigned equivalent (the detailed formal rule for this is quoted at the bottom of this answer).

---

Formal details can be found in C17 6.8.6.4/3 which says:

> If the expression has a type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

Where "as if by assignment" is the important part - it's the same rule as when using `=`. So we have to look up the rule for assignment 6.5.15.1:

> In *simple assignment* (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

This conversion happens implicitly, without the need for a cast - the casts in your examples are just clutter.

In the specific case, an integer conversion from signed to unsigned happens (6.3.1.3):

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
> subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.

Comment: The cast is not “nonsense.” It may be trivial or have no effect, but the meaning of it is clear and unambiguous. It has a sense and is not nonsensical. And such constructions might arise out of macros or formulaic code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There are no macros in the question I'm answering. Perhaps you are reading a different one?

Comment: My comment does not say there are macros in the question or rely on it. That is an example of how code that performs a cast in a `return` can arise.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement works as if by assignment, meaning that the behaviour of

```
FOO bar(void) 
{
    ...
    return baz;
}
```

is the same as

```
FOO bar(void)
{
    ...
    FOO return_value;
    return_value = baz;
    return returnValue;
}
```

`return baz;` is valid only iff assignment `return_value = baz;` is valid.

Now, for assignment (and likewise for `return`) the value of the right operand is converted to the value of left operand, so if your function returns `uint16_t`, then the value of the expression in the return statement is converted to `uint16_t` using the language rules.

If the conversion to `uint16_t` is valid without an explicit cast, as is true for integer and real floating types, then casting to `(uint16_t)` does not change anything. Pointers, however, do not have an implicit conversion to integers, hence if you try to do the *ill-advised* thing and return a pointer from this function coerced to `uint16_t`, you need an explicit cast.

From the above follows that:

```
static int16_t sResult_S16;

static uint16_t GetMyResult(void) 
{
    return sResult_S16;
}
```

is assembled so that the signed integer is converted to unsigned integer by converting it to a positive number modulo 65536. In practice, since you used exactly `int16_t` and `uint16_t`, the conversion will result in the exact same bit representation, but possibly zero-extended.

Answer (score 1):

We can organize this as three cases:

1. If the `return` expression has the same type as the return type of the function, it is returned to the caller without change.
2. If the `return` expression has a different type but it is similar according to certain constraints, it will be automatically converted to the return type of the function.
3. If the `return` expression has a type outside the constraints, the compiler will complain. The compiler might or might not continue to compile the program, depending on a variety of factors.

What this means for casts in the `return` expression is:

1. A cast to the return type of the function will have no effect, since the expression is already the necessary type. So it is unnecessary.
2. A cast to the return type of the function will have the same effect as the automatic conversion that would have occurred anyway. So it is unnecessary.
3. A cast to the return type of the function is necessary to avoid a compiler warning. Whether such a cast is correct depends on circumstances. There are casts that have defined and desired behavior but will not be performed automatically, but there are also casts that may have undefined or undesired behavior.

C 2018 6.8.6 4 3 says “… If the expression has a type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.” C 6.5.16.1 1 specifies constraints for assignments. Simplifying, they allow:

- Assigning a numeric type to a numeric type.
- Assigning a structure or union type to a compatible structure or union type.
- Assigning a pointer to a type to a pointer to a compatible type with at least the same qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`, `restrict`, and `_Atomic`).
- Assigning a pointer to void to a pointer to an object type or vice-versa, with at least the same qualifiers.
- Assigning a null pointer constant to a pointer.
- Assigning a pointer to a `_Bool`.

An example of a conversion that is defined but that is not automatically performed is converting an `int *` to `char *`. If a function declared to return `char *` has calculated some value in an `int *x` and wants to return it, it cannot use `return x;` because this does not satisfy any of the constraints listed above. However, `(char *) x` is defined (by C 2018 6.3.2.3 7), so `return (char *) x;` can be used.

Note that, while a compiler must accept `return` expressions that satisfy one of the listed constraints, it may produce a warning. That is, it can display a message warning the user of something possibly unintended, such as returning a `double` where the return type is `int` and thus possibly losing information without intending to, but the C standard requires the compiler to continue compiling the program anyway.

Comment: "A cast to the return type of the function is necessary to avoid a compiler warning." Compiler warnings in this context might be information about constraint violations. Adding a cast to dodge a constraint violation is likely incorrect and harmful, in case the types involved are not compatible or do not follow the constraints of simple assignment.

Comment: "a _Bool to a pointer." You got it backwards. The left operand may be a `_Bool` and assigned to from the right operand which may be a pointer. You cannot assign a `_Bool` to a pointer.

Comment: @Lundin: Re `_Bool`: Thanks, fixed. Re constraint violations: My answer covers this and gives an example. Converting an object pointer to `char *` is defined but not automatic: Trying to return a non-character object pointer for a `char *` function violates the constraints and so cannot be used in a `return` without at least getting a warning, but using a cast to convert it to `char *` does not violate constraints and is defined. But there are other conversions that may not be defined.